# Prometheus and InfluxDB as long time storage

Tags: linux, monitoring

I'm trying to connect prometheus to influxdb to store data longer than 15 days.
Grafana and Prometheus are working if promehteus isn't connected to influxdb.

Following I posted my error and all the configurations and parameters:

Execution of query on Prometheus with 1h works, with 1w not:
Error executing query: many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

**Grafana Query:**

```
node_time{instance=~"$node:$port"} - node_boot_time{instance=~"$node:$port"}
```

**Grafana Error Response:**

```
{

  "status": "error",
  "errorType": "execution",
  "error": "many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side",
  "message": "many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side"
}
```

**Grafana Error Request**

```
Url   api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query_range?
query=node_time%7Binstance%3D~%22btzhlprom01%3A9100%22%7D%20-%20node_boot_time%7Binstance%3D~%22btzhlprom01%3A9100%22%7D&start=1520764826&end=1520851226&step=1800
Method      GET
X-Grafana-Org-Id 1
Accept      application/json, text/plain, */*
```

**Prometheus Build Information**

```
Version     2.0.0
Revision    0a74f98628a0463dddc90528220c94de5032d1a0
Branch      HEAD
BuildUser   root@615b82cb36b6
BuildDate   20171108-07:11:59
GoVersion   go1.9.2
```

**Prometheus Command-Line Flags:**

```
alertmanager.notification-queue-capacity 10000
alertmanager.timeout    10s
completion-bash   false
completion-script-bash false
completion-script-zsh   false
config.file       /opt/prom/prometheus/prometheus.yml
help false
help-long   false
help-man    false
log.level   info
query.lookback-delta    5m
query.max-concurrency   20
query.timeout     2m
storage.tsdb.max-block-duration    36h
storage.tsdb.min-block-duration    2h
storage.tsdb.no-lockfile      false
storage.tsdb.path       /prometheus/
storage.tsdb.retention 15d
version     false
web.console.libraries   /opt/prom/prometheus/console_libraries
web.console.templates   /opt/prom/prometheus/consoles
web.enable-admin-api    false
web.enable-lifecycle    false
web.external-url http://prometheus.apl.dom
web.listen-address      127.0.0.1:9090
web.max-connections     512
web.read-timeout 5m
web.route-prefix /
web.user-assets
```

**Prometheus Config:**

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 10s
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      - alertmanager.apl.dom:443
    tls_config:
      ca_file: /opt/prom/prometheus/ApprenticeLab.pem
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    scheme: https
    timeout: 10s
rule_files:
- /opt/prom/prometheus/alerts/disk.yml
- /opt/prom/prometheus/alerts/uptime.yml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: prometheus
  scrape_interval: 10s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - prometheus.apl.dom
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /opt/prom/prometheus/TrustedRootCertificate.cer
    insecure_skip_verify: true
- job_name: grafana
  scrape_interval: 10s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - grafana.apl.dom:443
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /opt/prom/prometheus/TrustedRootCertificate.cer
    insecure_skip_verify: true
- job_name: nodes
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  file_sd_configs:
  - files:
    - /opt/prom/prometheus/targets/infra.json
    - /opt/prom/prometheus/targets/testing.json
    refresh_interval: 5m
remote_write:
- url: http://btzhlinflx01:8086/api/v1/prom/write?u=prometheus&p=prometheus&db=prometheus
  remote_timeout: 30s
  queue_config:
    capacity: 100000
    max_shards: 1000
    max_samples_per_send: 100
    batch_send_deadline: 5s
    max_retries: 10
    min_backoff: 30ms
    max_backoff: 100ms
remote_read:
- url: http://btzhlinflx01:8086/api/v1/prom/read?u=prometheus&p=prometheus&db=prometheus
  remote_timeout: 1m
  read_recent: true
```

Comment: I have this problem. In prometheus, if I query data 23 days old. I get the "many-to-many" error, but when I query in influxdb, I have older data. I thought it might be the `capacity: 100000` but influx says I have 71,490 data points in a certain series.